# Error in a Phoenix template list

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm trying to  extract values form a list (`<%= @evento %>`) in a template but I'm getting this error:

```
lists in Phoenix.HTML and templates may only contain integers representing bytes, binaries or other lists, got invalid entry: %Skeleton.News.Evento{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "news_eventos">, date: "DEZ 2011", id: 69, imgPaths: ["images/fabasa/eventos/one/1.jpg", "images/fabasa/eventos/one/2.jpg", "images/fabasa/eventos/one/3.jpg", "images/fabasa/eventos/one/10.jpg"], inserted_at: ~N[2017-06-30 12:38:15.452214],...
```

So, my question is how to transform this in a datatype structure that I can still iterate in my template?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot print a list like that in a template because templates only allow iolists to be printed, which are lists containing integers, binaries (also called `String` in Elixir), or iolists.

If you want to print the `inspect` representation of the list (the one you see in `iex`), you can do:

```
<%= inspect @evento %>
```

To iterate through the list, you can use `for`:

```
<%= for event <- @evento %>
  <%= event.id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, correct but then when I do `<%= inspect i.imgPaths[0] %>` (which is my final goal) I get an error: `the Access calls for keywords expect the key to be an atom, got: 0` and I can't understand why because it is a list of strings...

Comment: You cannot use bracket indexing for lists. You can use `Enum.at(i.imgPaths, 0)` or just `hd(i.imgPaths)` which returns the head of the list.

Comment: Oh my...Yes. Thank you!

Comment: @Dogbert I think you're missing `do` on your first line: `<%= for event <- @evento do %>`.